# What is the shortcut for find variable not used In Netbeans?

Tags: java, netbeans

Does anyone know how to find some variables not used in Netbeans, like when I create the variable `String a` and I hover over that variable I get the info `Variable "a" is not used`?
I want to jump into that variable because in my servlet there are too many lines.

Comment: **Window > Action Items** (Ctrl + 6) will do this for you. Just double click the line with the relevant message in the **Action Items** window and it will send you to the offending source line in the code.

Comment: @skomisa Is this a new feature? I'm at the moment on NetBeans 8.2 and even if I select all types in the action item filter I don't see any warnings regarding unused variables.

Comment: @JoachimRohde You are right  - my apologies. Unfortunately my comment was incomplete. I should have also mentioned that: [1] You first need to [install the **EasyPMD** plugin](https://github.com/giancosta86/EasyPmd). [2] Ensure that **Show All** is selected in the **Action** Item filter. I verified this works using EasyPMD (_"Version: 10.0 Source: Plugin Portal"_) and NetBeans 8.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not aware of any functionality that comes out of the box. But some third party tools offer you what you are searching for:

- [PMD](https://pmd.github.io/) (especially [this rule](https://pmd.github.io/pmd-6.14.0/pmd_rules_java_bestpractices.html#unusedlocalvariable)). There's also a [NetBeans plugin](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/57270/easypmd) although I don't know if it works with the newest version of NetBeans.
- [SpotBugs](https://spotbugs.github.io/) (search for [unused](https://spotbugs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/bugDescriptions.html?highlight=unused) in the documentation to find the rules)